# How to access div id (with runat="server") on MasterPage via User Control?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, user-controls

We have masterpage with DIV id="new-div". We have deployed a user control on this masterpage. I would like to know how can we access the new-div via the user control?

We need to add some css based on the logged in user and other details.

Is this possible?

Comment: do u know the id?

Comment: Yes I do. Its a custom div that is created by myself on th4e master page with DIV ID="test1"

Comment: so @Unnie is correct. U can use jQuery and add a class on  that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this.use the below script to add class in the user control.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var className='class1';//here write logic for   deciding the classname  .


$('div[id*="new-div"]').addClass(className);

});
```

Comment: but i want to write code in usercontrol based on some output value of SP object model list item value

Comment: i did not understand it can you explain this to me

Comment: You can write your logic to decide the className to be applied using server side code.Store that class value in a hiddenfield and using jquery assign the hiddenfield value to div .addClass method